# Find a point that minimizes $\alpha(PA^2+PB^2+PC^2)+\beta(PA+PB+PC)$

Tags: vectors, triangles, plane-geometry

Is there a simple way to find a point $P$ in a $2\mbox{D}$ plane that minimizes  $$\alpha(PA^2+PB^2+PC^2)+\beta(PA+PB+PC),$$
where $\alpha,\beta>0$? If $\alpha=0$, the answer is the Fermat point of $\triangle ABC$, while if $\beta=0$, the answer is the center of gravity of $\triangle ABC$. For general $\alpha,\beta$, how do I express the point $P$ (or vector $\overrightarrow{OP}$ from the origin $O$) in terms of $\,\overrightarrow{OA}$, $\overrightarrow{OB}$, and $\overrightarrow{OC}$?

I tried putting everything in coordinates and find that $\,PA+PB+PC\,$ gives sum of square roots, which is not easy to minimize. The result also looks messy. So I hope to find a neat answer with the help of planar vectors.

Comment: I also tried rewriting the function as $(PA+\gamma)^2+(PB+\gamma)^2+(PC+\gamma)^2$, where $\gamma=\beta/2\alpha$. But still, it's not easy to get an expression for the optimal $P$.

Answer (score 0):

One possible approach would be to use Cauchy-Schwartz $$\Big(\alpha\sum_{A,B,C}PA^2+\beta\sum_{A,B,C}PA\Big)\Big(\dfrac{1}{\alpha}+\dfrac{1}{\beta}\Big)\geq\Big(\sqrt{\sum_{A,B,C}PA^2}+\sqrt{\sum_{A,B,C}PA}\Big)^2$$
then try to see if the point at which the latter is minimized could be expressed nicely. Obviously, there exists such a global minimum and thus a choice of $P$ gives the minimal value, but I sense that you are more interested in knowing if such a choice of $P$ is expressed nicely.

Comment: A global minimum should exist because both $PA^2+PB^2+PC^2$ and $PA+PB+PC$ are convex functions of the coordinates of $P$ (because $PA$, $PB$, and $PC$ are all convex).

Comment: Separately minimizing $PA^2+PB^2+PC^2$ and $PA+PA+PC$ would give a lower bound that cannot be achieved unless the centroid coincides with the Fermat point.

Comment: Of course. If I were to attack this further, I would write $\vec{P} = a\vec{T}+b\vec{M}$, and then turn this into a function of $a,b$, where $T$ is the toricelli point, $M$ centroid. Furthermore, I have a suspicion that the minimum is attained when $a+b=1$ and $a,b >0$, which is the same thing as $P$ is a point on the line segment $TM.$

Comment: I tried an example numerically. Unfortunately $P$ was not on the line $TM$.

Comment: if that's the case, then I am afraid the general solution will not have a nice-looking formula.